# creating winhttp array in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I want to know if it is possible to create an array for winhttp just like we can do with winsock control.

Here is my code to send out request once using proxy.

```
Dim result As String
Dim URL As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object
Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "http://example.com"
winHttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", Text2.Text
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Keep-Alive", "115"
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
winHttpReq.SetProxy 2, List1.text, ""
winHttpReq.Send
```

List1.text is  ip:port

How can I create array so that I can send out request with all the IP that is in list1, rather then sending it 1 by 1?

Comment: `Dim winHttpReq(1) As Object` ?

Comment: then do i continue adding Dim winHttpReq(2) As Object so on ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - do you mean to ask about how many array elements you need to use? That's up to you - how many do you want to try to run?  Remember that the default base is 0, so `Dim winHttpReq(5) as Object` will create 6 array elements, with indices of 0 to 5.

Comment: may i ask when using proxy how come the ui hangs for few seconds then it works again.  i wish to use list1 proxy list and it gives hell of a problem freezing up.

Comment: I have never tried your particular code processing here, but it's probably normal and expected.  You're making a call to the proxy server and you're just going to need to wait for it to respond.  VB6 is single threaded - everything runs on the main UI thread, so when you make a blocking call it will have the impact of locking or freezing the UI. If you run this code on a background thread, that'll resolve your UI lockup syndrome, but running multiple threads directly in VB6 isn't easy and is fragile, a better option would be to create a .Net COM assembly, and use background threading in there.

Comment: mark is it possible i can have live chat with u please , i promise i wil not take much of your time buddy